# How can you connect to a postgresql database on heroku from google-colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Just started using colaboratory and would like to run sql queries against a postgresql db.  Is this possible on colaboratory.  I've used magic sql with jupyter nb to do this.

Comment: In principle, any Jupyter notebook should work in Colab. Do you have a sample that fails? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It was a matter of using 2 %% instead of 1 that was giving me an error.  What I'm running is this:

```
! pip install ipython-sql
! pip install psycopg2 
%sql postgres://<connect string>
%sql select tablename from pg_tables;
```

I saw an example where there sql was run with %%sql and when I tried that I got an error.
Everything is running well now.
Rebecca